# Python Printing Matrix

Tags: python

Can you help me in how to print this on the right way? I've tried many ways but none work'd

```
while True:
    m = int(input())
    mlen = m
    sm = 1
    aux = 1
    matriz = []

    if m == 0:
        print()
        break

    for i in range(m):
        linha = []
        for j in range(m):
            linha.append(sm)
        matriz.append(linha)

    while m - 2 > 0:
        for i in range(aux, m - 1):
            for j in range(aux, m - 1):
                matriz[i][j] = sm + 1
        sm += 1
        aux += 1
        m -= 1
    for i in matriz:
        for j in i:
            print('{:4}'.format(j), end='')
        print('')
```

I have to print the matrix as the example below. It's an URI Online Judge exercise (num 1435). The dots below are spaces and I can't have any after the last element of the matrix.

```
    Accepted Output             Your Output
1   ··1···1···1···1         1   ···1···1···1···1
2   ··1···2···2···1         2   ···1···2···2···1
3   ··1···2···2···1         3   ···1···2···2···1
4   ··1···1···1···1         4   ···1···1···1···1
6   ··1···1···1···1···1     6   ···1···1···1···1···1
7   ··1···2···2···2···1     7   ···1···2···2···2···1
8   ··1···2···3···2···1     8   ···1···2···3···2···1
9   ··1···2···2···2···1     9   ···1···2···2···2···1
10  ··1···1···1···1···1     10  ···1···1···1···1···1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.rjust(width[, fillchar])`, you can then use the `fillchar` to get the dots

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rjust#str.rjust

Comment: Hello, I've tried this, but I don't know how to remove the extra space on the first column. I need to have 3 spaces between the characters and they need to be aligned to the right.